# AsUnit verses FlexUnit – which is "better"?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flexunit, asunit

I'm learning ActionScript/Flex at the moment, and it's come time for me to start unit testing.  My reading shows that there are two main frameworks out there: FlexUnit and AsUnit.

Is there any reason to learn one over the other? Is one, in some way, "better"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is also [fluint](http://code.google.com/p/fluint/), which was created in order to address issues that developers were running into using FlexUnit.

Because of new FlexUnit tooling support in the upcoming FlashBuilder 4 release from Adobe, the fluint project and the FlexUnit project have merged to create a new unit testing suite now dubbed FlexUnit 4.0.  The FlashBuilder IDE will support FlexUnit 4.0 at the tool-level.  This new tooling support, coupled with some of the [great new features of FlexUnit 4.0](http://blogs.digitalprimates.net/codeSlinger/index.cfm/2009/5/3/FlexUnit-4-in-360-seconds), make the new FlexUnit the clear choice for unit testing in ActionScript 3 and Flex code.

Answer (score 5):

I think it depends on the kind of ActionScript development you're doing. AsUnit has a wider set a supported versions.

FlexUnit looks as though it has a better backing through Adobe. If you're focusing on Flex development (or strictly AS3), I'd probably go with FlexUnit.

Answer (score 1):

As a followup to this question, I have been using FlexUnit for the last bunch of months, and it (along with Drew Bourn's awesome [hamcrest-as3](http://github.com/drewbourne/hamcrest-as3)) has been making me very happy.